# UITableView is laggy when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which becomes very laggy during scrolling. 
Images are saved in an array from JSON (in viewDidLoad) and my code for images in cellForRowAtIndexPath is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"UserDiscountsTableViewCell";

UserDiscountsTableViewCell *cell = (UserDiscountsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserDiscountsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}


cell.userDiscountNameLabel.text = [userDiscountName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.userDiscountImages.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userDiscountImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];


return cell;
```

}

I am using a custom UITableViewCell. When I remove the part of code with cell.userDiscountImages.image everything is working perfect.

Can anyone advise what might be the cause of the laggy scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your question yourself : if you remove the line were you set the image, everything works fine. This line takes a lot of time to process and has you do it on the main thread, you block the UI.

Try using Grand Central Dispatch to send the image initialization to a background thread. When the initialization is done, you need to go back on the main thread and then, you can do your UI update. This will look something like this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userDiscountImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UserDiscountsTableViewCell *discountCell = (UserDiscountsTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        discountCell.userDiscountImages.image = img
    });
});
```

Note that after initializing the image, I don't set it directly on the cell, I fetch it back from the `UITableView` : it's because by the time the image has loaded, the cell could have been reused to display another cell at another `NSIndexPath`. If you don't do it this way, you may end up with the wrong image in the wrong cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your table view is lagging because your are performing networking code on the main thread when you are loading your image. See the apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:

This open source library is a good way to handle async image loading: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage